# Android moveTaskToBack also hides Applications that launched calling Application

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am developing 2 apps that will run in separate processes and communicate much like a client-server would through Android's `Messenger` IPC medium.

App A, the server application, establishes a `Bound Service` that can be externally, explicitly launched by App B, the client application, to request for a connection and to execute some operations.

App B, the client application, establishes it's own `Bound Service` - to explicitly launch and maintain contact with App A's `Bound Service` - that is bound at the `Application` level and interacted with by different `Activities`, giving the latter feedback through their `Handler` instances.

In some instances, App A's `Bound Service` needs to trigger a sequence of `Activity` launches specially scripted to establish necessary requirements for it's Server function to work correctly, after being polled by App B's `Bound Service`. However, once they are set up, I need to bring App B back to the foreground for the User to interact with.

In that particular App A's Activity, I implement `moveTaskToBack(true)` in `onBackPressed()` to prevent the User from accidentally closing the application by default, and intended to simply call `onBackPressed()` to reveal App B's task when launched in the above mentioned manner.

However, even though App B has `Activities` running and was in the foreground when App B's `Service` called App A's `Service`, which in turn launched App A's `Activities` to the foreground, calling `onBackPressed()` from App A's `Activity` ***sends the User straight back to the Home Screen, bypassing App B.***

**How do I simply tell App A to send itself to the background and reveal App B, without sending App B to the background as well? And why does `moveTaskToBack()` move every other Task to the back too?**

Answer (score 0):

So, I have not found the exact manner to inform App A to send itself, and not the task (App B) that launched it, to the background, but I have found a way to simply tell App A to send App B in front of it, which works for me.

Through the Messenger spanning both Bound Services, I send App B's `taskID`, obtained from any of its `Activities` through `getTaskID()`, by passing it in a Bundle which is the `msg.obj` of my Message sent through the Messenger instance.

Then, by carrying the Bundle through all the chained Intents that launch subsequent Activities in App A, I can access the `taskID` in the target `Activity` in App A, and use

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.moveTaskToFront(taskID, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
```

to send App B to the foreground instead. When back is pressed on App B's `Activity` (onBackPressed() is not overridden there), I find myself back on App A, which seems odd for the `MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME` flag, but it is not of much bother to me.

**I am still open to answers for the original question and will set that as the correct answer if there are any, however.**